# ienumerable vs list<T>

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

It is said that IEnumerable is used in a custom collection. One of the uses is the foreach loop used to traverse through the custom collection.

However my question is that instead of making a custom collection that first implements `IEnumerable` and then constructing another class to implement `IEnumerator` to store a group of custom objects, why can't we just use `list<your_customer_object>`.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: "It is said" by who?

Comment: That wouldn't be a **custom** collection.

Comment: @phresnel - Ah, the same "they" from "they say..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you might want to implement a different data structure. `IEnumerable` abstracts the concept of sequence, while a `List` has the concept of index, adding/removing items and its own, data structure.

As an example of different structure, here's a class which allows you to enter an infinite `foreach` loop.

```
public class InfiniteSequence : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new InfiniteEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    class InfiniteEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            Current++;
            return true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Current = 0;
        }

        public int Current { get; private set; }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use `List<T>`.

If `List<T>` fits your needs, then use it and don't create a new class that inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You would provide your own implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` when `List<T>` isn't right for your needs.  The canonical example of this is when you want to support lazy evaluation of your collection, perhaps with a method that uses `yield return`.

Answer (score 1):

As @ken2k said, you can just `List<T>` and you will got a generic version of List with your T type. But if you want to hide this implementation and customize some operations that `List<T>` or include new features, you can inherits from the List and implement your own methods. For sample:

```
public class CustomerCollection : List<Customer> // at this time, you have all methods from List such as Add, Remove, [index] etc...
{
   public double AverageAge()
   {
       return this.Average(customer => customer.Age)
   }

   // other methods...
}
```

`IEnumeralbe` is the most abstraction of collections in .Net Framework, you can just interate in this abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `List<T>` or any other of the generic collection types. After all `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Do you have a particular edge case that you need to cover with a bespoke collection?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can define your members as `List<T>`, that however binds the customer of your class to a specific implementation. If you define the member as `IEnumerable<T>` (assuming that the consumers will only want to enumerate your collection) than you can change the implementation to a different collection type that implements the interface without breaking the contract. You if you change it from `List<T>` to `SortedSet<T>` to implement order your consumers are not affected.

It's basically the advantage of coding against interfaces rather than concrete types.

You can use a different interface, ie. `ICollection<T>` if your consumers want more than just enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't do anything else, go ahead. Specialized collections are for collections that need to do... special... things.

(For example, a `ListViewItemCollection` would have to notify its parent `ListView` when updated, so it needs to implement `IList(T)`, and therefore `IEnumerable(T)`. If you had a custom collection, it might inherit from that. Inheriting only from `IEnumerable(T)` makes sense only when your collection can be enumerated, but not indexed.)

Answer (score 0):

You Can.

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
IEnumerable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of confusion here is the difference between a "custom collection" and a "collection of custom class instances". Of these two, your `List<CustomObject>` is the latter case - you are only reusing a collection created by someone else and taking advantage of generics to keep the item type info, that's all. Truly custom collection would probably implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but you will rarely (if ever) need it.

So in this case you not only can, but probably also *should* use `List<CustomObject>`